# ¿Debo usar los 2 apellidos de figuras históricas latinoamericanas en la traducción de un libro del español al inglés?

Tags: traducción, nombres-propios, inglés

No sé si este es el grupo apropiado para preguntar sobre este tema, pero me interesa saber lo que piensan. 
Estoy traduciendo un libro escrito en español al inglés. Es un libro sobre un periodo de la historia de Centroamérica. Siguiendo la costumbre usada en el español, el autor puso los personajes en el texto usando sus dos apellidos. En el inglés solo se usa un apellido, solo el apellido paterno, no el materno. Muchas personas que solo hablan el inglés no saben cómo se usan los apellidos en el español y cuando encuentran alguien quien usa los dos apellidos asumen que el primer apellido es el segundo nombre y que el segundo apellido es el apellido paterno, un error que quiero evitar. ¿Existe una regla o costumbre sobre cual de los apellidos se debe utilizar cuando se traduce del español al inglés?
Pienso poner una nota del traductor al principio del la traducción del libro al ingles explicando que solo se utilizó el apellido paterno, siguiendo la costumbre inglesa, pero indicar que he puesto un apéndice al final con una lista de todos los personajes con ambos apellidos, siguiendo la costumbre española, para el lector a quien le interese saber esto. ¿Qué opinan?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio! Es una pregunta interesante, pero si te fijas quienes mejor te van a saber responder a esta pregunta son aquellos que tengan el inglés como lengua materna. Tal vez sea recomendable hacer esta misma pregunta en el sitio de inglés a ver qué opinan allí. Yo sinceramente tendría la misma duda que tú, por lo que no sabría decirte.

Comment: @walen mejor que ELU sería Writing https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hoy día la norma es dejar los nombres tal y como aparecen en la obra original.  Me parece bien que pongas una nota de traductor al principio y un apéndice con los personajes.

Comment: I agree with the others that you would be better to ask on a different site. You might also need to specify your audience in case there are regional differences in customs. I suspect the answer is that anything goes.

Comment: Graicias por sus respuestas! Sí no encontré una parte de Stack Exchange especificamente sobre la traducción, por eso pensé en pregunatles aquí. Pero sí, voy a seguir sus consejos y preguntar en otros espacios.

Comment: @walen Este nick viene porque soy antropologo y me especialice en la cultura de los Maya. En la ciudad de Copán hubo un rey llamado Jaguar Luna. Una vez me quería hacer miembro de un sitio y todos los nicks de usuario ya estaban tomados, incluyendo Jaguar Moon. Entonces cambie el orden de los nombres y use ceros para crear un nick original

Comment: @mdewey I agree that this question is better asked in another area. My book is written in Honduran Spanish and it is being translated into American English, to be published in that market. I have searched online for an answer, but I have not found any discussions of this issue so far. And you are correct that anything goes- the translator has a lot of discretion. Translation is an art, not a science.

Comment: You could flag it for migration to writing, where I think it would probably be considered on topic, but quicker might be to post it there, leave the new address in a comment here, and finally delete the original.  (Those with a certain amount of reputation will be able to see the deleted post and its comments, and thus will be able to find your new question.)